# How to include double quote in CloudWatch Logs filter?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

> Enclose exact phrases and terms that include non-alphanumeric characters in double quotation marks ("").
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Then, how should I include a double quote itself in query?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the double quote with backslash: `\"`